# Calculate distance (time) between ordered rows of grouped variables using dplyr and tidyr

Tags: r, time, dplyr, tidyr, difference

I would like to assign the time difference to the last entry within each group.

This is my toy data set (dfx):

```
vals<- 1:5 
grps <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
dts <- as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05"))
dfx <- as_tibble(cbind(vals,grps,dts))
colnames(dfx) <- c("vals","grps","dts")
(dfx <- dfx %>% mutate(dts = as.Date(dts)))
```

dfx is a 5 x 3 tibble:

```
   vals  grps dts       
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1     1     1 2020-01-01
2     2     1 2020-01-02
3     3     2 2020-01-03
4     4     2 2020-01-04
5     5     2 2020-01-05
```

`grps` is a grouping variable; here it contains 2 groups (1,2).
My desired output would be the distance (in days) from the last day of each group, and should look like `rslt` (my toy result):

```
bfr <-as.tibble(c(1,0,2,1,0))
colnames(bfr) <- "dist"
(rslt <- bind_cols(dfx,bfr))
```

```
   vals  grps dts         dist
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1     1     1 2020-01-01     1
2     2     1 2020-01-02     0
3     3     2 2020-01-03     2
4     4     2 2020-01-04     1
5     5     2 2020-01-05     0
```

If possible, I would like to use `dplyr`, `lubridate`, and `tidyr` to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your dates are arranged in order. Use `group_by` to group by `grps`, and then take difference between the `last(dts)` and each row.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfx %>% 
  mutate(dts = as.Date(dts, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  arrange(dts) %>%
  group_by(grps) %>%
  mutate(dist = as.numeric(last(dts) - dts))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   grps [2]
   vals  grps dts         dist
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1     1     1 2020-01-01     1
2     2     1 2020-01-02     0
3     3     2 2020-01-03     2
4     4     2 2020-01-04     1
5     5     2 2020-01-05     0
```

Comment: Hey @Ben, 
Your solution works fine. It took me quite some time to figure out, that if using the grouping on a factor e.g. `ddfx %>% 
  mutate(dts = as.Date(dts)) %>%
  mutate(dts = as.factor(grps)) %>% 
  arrange(dts) %>%
  group_by(grps) %>%
  mutate(dist = as.numeric(last(dts) - dts))` it won't work. (I included an 'as.numeric()' to get it going)

Comment: Sorry, was sending the comment too early. Now edited.

Comment: It looks like you convert `dts` to a `Date` object with `mutate`, but then on the following line change `dts` to a factor. When you do that, the object is of class `factor` and not `Date` any longer. If you want to calculate difference between dates, you want to subtract one `Date` object from another `Date` object, as opposed to subtracting a factor from another.

Comment: Well, actually in my real-world dataset it was a factor. Unfortunately, **when running it in a chunk in Rmd it didn't give me a warning** - like it does, when running a similar code in the console:`In Ops.factor(last(dts), dts) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`.